# Convert Tz-aware datetime.datetime to datetime64/DatetimeIndex/Timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am using a PostgreSQL database to store and retrieve data. The columns I get are:

1. date : timestamp with timezone
2. value: double precision
3. type : character varying (approximate geographical location of the data)
4. code: character varying (code related to the exact geographical location)

This is how I get my data using `pd.read_sql_query`:

```
df     = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT date, value FROM my_db WHERE code ='%s' and type = '%s' and date >= '%s' and date <= '%s' ORDER BY date;"
                            % (code, type, start_date, end_date), con=Cdc.engine, index_col="date")
df["value"].replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan, inplace=True)  # replace 0 by NaN since 0 is an error in my data
```

**Then I try to do the following, and this is where I get my error:**

```
df = df[df.index.month.isin(wanted_month)]
```

Which returns me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'month'
```

**1. I tried to fix this by doing:**

```
self.df_cdc.index = pd.to_datetime(self.df_cdc.index)
```

But it does not work since I get this error:

```
ValueError: Array must be all same time zone
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

**2. I also tried to do:**

```
df = df[df.index.dt.month.isin(wanted_month)]
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Here is an example of the index values of my DF:

```
#   2019-12-30 21:10:00+01:00 --> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
#   2019-10-11 15:00:00+02:00 --> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Those are french data, so we have daylight saving time with +1 hour in winter and +2 in summer compared to UTC (e.g. : `winter: UTC = 10h00 --> France = 11h00; summer: UTC = 10h00 --> France = 12h00`).

Displaying tzinfo gives me this :

```
print(df.index[0], "-->", df.index[0].tzinfo)
print(df.index[15000], "-->", df.index[15000].tzinfo
2019-01-01 00:00:00+01:00 --> psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=60, name=None)
2019-04-15 05:00:00+02:00 --> psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=120, name=None)
```

Thank you for your attention.

**EDIT: I found the solution and posted it below.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by converting first to UTC, and then back to my timezone (I verified and the dates and times are correct:

```
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(self.df_cdc.index, utc=True)
    df.index = self.df_cdc.index.tz_convert("Europe/Paris")
```

This is the complete query:

```
df     = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT date, value FROM my_db WHERE code ='%s' and type = '%s' and date >= '%s' and date <= '%s' ORDER BY date;"
                                % (code, type, start_date, end_date), con=Cdc.engine, index_col="date")
df["value"].replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan, inplace=True)  # replace 0 by NaN since 0 is an error in my data
df.index = pd.to_datetime(self.df_cdc.index, utc=True)
df.index = self.df_cdc.index.tz_convert("Europe/Paris")
```

Comment: In your query you can use `select date at time zone 'Europe/Paris'` or `select date at time zone 'UTC'`.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue after reading tz-aware datetimes into a pandas df.  First `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`, then, when converting to UTC in order to oblige `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.  I also had to convert my datetime column `dtm` to UTC and back:  
   
`df['dtm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtm'], utc=True)`  and  
    `df['dtm'] = df['dtm'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')`.   I have no idea why thiis is necessary - did you find that out?